# EF core request cannot wake-up Azure Sql (serverless sku) database and times out

Tags: entity-framework-core, azure-sql-database

I'm using EF Core with one of my apps to query an Azure Sql database. It's the serverless sku, that scales down to zero (goes to sleep) after 1h of inactivity.

Now, in that app there is scheduled function to query the database at certain points in time. This often is in a time, where the DB is sleeping. To compensate for this, I'm using the the following in the DbContext.cs

```cs
optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(connection, opt => opt.EnableRetryOnFailure(
    maxRetryCount: 20,
    maxRetryDelay: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30),
    errorNumbersToAdd: null
));
```

If the delay is evenly distributed, that results in an avg of 15s, with 20 retries => timeout after 5mins.

I thought this should be plenty, since when querying a sleeping database with SSMS it usaully takes well under 1min to get going. However, this is not the case, the functions regularly time-out and the queries fail.

Is there a better way to deal with this than just even more increasing the timeout? Should 5mins really not be enough?

Cheers

Comment: Increase the connection timeout?

Comment: Okay, I might try this. Although the delay is already 30s with 20 retries, thus 10mins. This already seems too much to be honest. Because when connecting manually using SSMS to a sleeping database it takes under 1 minnto wake up/connect.

Comment: Re SSMS - that sounds starange to have such a big difference, both EF and SSMS use similar underlying tech to connect. The dfault Connect timeout with SSMS is only 30 seconds !?

Comment: Can't say currently due to lack of access to pc. But I didn't change the defaults

Comment: It's 30s in SSMS

Comment: Btw, I edited the question to focus more on the discrepancy in behaviours of EF Core vs SSMS

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think I got it working now. The above code snippet from EF core is relevant to any `command timeout` occurences. However, since the database was sleeping during the request it was rather a `connection timeout` issue. I fixed this, by providing adding `Connect Timeout=120` in the connection string itself.